# Using What if tool with xgboost

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, xgboost

I am trying to use what if tool on my xgboost model. 
But on the [link](https://pair-code.github.io/what-if-tool/) I am only able to find examples of xgboost used through google AI Platform. Is there any way we can use whatif tool on XGboost without Google AI platform

I tried the functions that were used in examples for tensorflow and keras and used functions set_estimator_and_feature_spec and set_compare_custom_predict_fn

```
bst = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    objective='reg:logistic'
)
bst.fit(x_train, y_train)

test_examples = df_to_examples(df_test)
config_builder = WitConfigBuilder(test_examples).set_custom_predict_fn(xg.predict)
WitWidget(config_builder)
```

When trying to perform run inference, an error msg is displayed `cannot initialize DMatrix from a list` and I am not unable to do it

Comment: i had the same problem. The XGBoost model needs to be served through a TensorFlow Model Server to work

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trial and error I finally got it to work with XGBoost using the following code:

```
# first argument in my case is a Pandas dataframe of all features and the target 'label'; 
# extract just the numpy array with 'values', then convert that to a list
# second argument is the column name as a list
# I use a sklearn pipeline, so here I am just accessing the classifier model which is an XGBClassifier instance
# Wit tool expects a 2D array, where the 1st dimension is each sample, and 2nd dimension is probabilities of
# each class; so use 'predict_proba' over 'predict'
config_builder = (WitConfigBuilder(df_sample.values.tolist(), df_sample.columns.tolist())
    .set_custom_predict_fn(clf['classifier'].predict_proba)
    .set_target_feature('label')
    .set_label_vocab(['No Churn', 'Churn']))
```

This eliminated the need to use their suggested helper functions and works out-of-the-box with Pandas DataFrames and Sklearn ML Models

Comment: Thanks a lot, was struggling to get it to work as well from my side. This worked. Upvoted